# How to make a REST API out of an executable

Tags: http, unix, server, webserver, cgi

Say I have an executable in my environment: `myscript`, which accepts command line arguments like `myscript -m <HTTP Request Headers + Body string>`.

How can I turn this into an API? I'm looking to have my server listen to HTTP requests on a specific URL and then pass this onto the executable, await for the output of the executable and then package that into a response and ship that to the client.

Using a Flask app I could do something like:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main(methods = ['POST']):
    data = request.form
    stream = os.system(f"myscript -m {data}")
    output = stream.read()
    return output
```

However, I'm not sure that this is common practice or if it's a bad idea.

The reason why I thought about this is because the executable `myscript` is written in a language that does not have a great web framework, but has some features that make it great for my use case.

Comment: Are you looking for CGI? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can work.  25 years ago [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) was a very common standard approach to dynamic website content, and it was more or less what you are doing here (it passed some of the data via environment variables too).

CGI has fallen out of favor.  It is a challenge to secure, as it involves executing an arbitrary file on the server.  If you see /cgi-bin/ in a URL, that's because they're locking down CGI to only work within that folder for security reasons.  It also suffers from performance issues as servers scale because it has to open up a new process for every request.  But it does technically still work.

You might want to look into Flask's native support for CGI and see whether that meets your needs.  It's typically better to rely on something that has had a lot of hours put into its design and validation.